# what could stop javascript timer event?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a simple JS timer which runs every 10 seconds and should send an AJAX request. The problem is that on some windows XP machines this task stops running - no AJAX request is sent. It seems to run successfully for 45 minutes and then stop for a random amount of time, then start and run successfully for another 45 minutes...my question is what could be causing this to happen? Could some service/scheduled task running on the PC stop javascript timers from working?

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var task = {
        run: function(){
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'test.php'
            });
        },
        interval: 10000
    };
    Ext.TaskManager.start(task);    

});
```

Comment: Looking at the task manager doesn't seem to reveal anything - the CPU/memory usage doesn't increase around the time that the JS timer stops working.

Comment: 45 mins? Check if the runtime froze. Script performance do degrade over time when left running for long periods, even if it's not taking much memory or CPU usage.

Comment: How do I check this? Is this in the task manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of suggestions:

1. Try to switch from `Ext.TaskManager` to a normal `setInterval`. If that fixes the problem there's probably a bug in Task Manager.
2. If it doesn't work then try the following:

   - Keep using intervals. Record the `id` of the interval. Also record the time of last execution.
   - Start another timer with `setInterval` and larger interval, say 1 minute. Inside the callback check for the last execution time.
   - If it was long ago (> 30 seconds), call `clearInterval` with the `id` that you stored and restart the task interval.
3. If that doesn't work try executing these polling tasks in a separate `<iframe>`. A browser can skip calling Interval and Timeout callbacks if it's busy with other tasks. By putting them into a separate `<iframe>` you give them a dedicated event loop, so that other tasks won't interfere with them.

Comment: Thanks - I'm now trying your first solution - just need to wait for around 45 minutes to see if it stops working...

Comment: The first suggestion worked - it must be a bug in the Ext taskmanager!

Comment: Great to hear that! It might be a good idea to report a bug to [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/).